# SQL Datetime query

Tags: sql, sqlite

Given a database, having table named as users with id and created_at field. Id is smallint type and created_at is datetime type.Want to know the people registered for every month.

The database am using is SQLite.

Wrote this simple query which supposed to be working but it gives an error. Could you please help me out.

```
select count(id) as Orders, DATEPART(mm,created_at) AS Ordermonth
from users
Group by DATEPART(mm,created_at);
```

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Your query uses SQL Server functions.  Your question is tagged "mysql" and "sqlite".  No wonder you are having problems.

Comment: THE ERROR I AM GETTING IS.. no such column: mm...

Answer (score 3):

The equivalent in SQLite would look like:

```
Select count(id) as Orders, strftime('%Y-%m', created_at) AS Ordermonth
From users
Group by strftime('%Y-%m', created_at)
Order by Ordermonth;
```

Your code looks like SQL Server code.

Comment: Thanks so much , the code worked out... But I have a question, why I can`t use the datepart function?

Comment: @user1932914 . . . Because it doesn't exist in SQLite.  Similarly, `strftime()` doesn't exist in any other database except SQLite.